# Rails IDs gives 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-postgresql

In my rails App, I have a Movies table and a Genres table. Genres need to have a specific `:id` so that the association between the movies and the genres can work properly. I can't change the genres id.

A while ago i created all the genres in the rails console as such

```
g = Genre.new
g.name = "Action"
g.id = 23
g.save!

g = Genre.new 
g.name = "Comedy"
g.id = 1034
g.save!
```

This saved and created the Genres and worked with the given :id, so if I went to /genres/23
it'll take me to the Action Genre.

Before launch I reset the whole database and recreated then genres.

But if i now run

```
g = Genre.new 
g.name = "Comedy"
g.id = 1034
g.save!
```

I get a 404 error when i try to go /genres/1034, but if i go to the genres/index page, Comedy is still being listed.

If i create a Genre without specifying the id, I don't get an error.

I've reset the Genre table and i've used [this gem](https://github.com/splendeo/activerecord-reset-pk-sequence)  but i still get a 404. It's like PostgreSQL is only remembering the ids `1034` and `23` and if i try to use them again, it gives a 404

Anyone have a solution to this? How can I create genres with previously used and destroyed IDs

*Genre.rb*

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

has_many :movies
end
```

*Genre#show*

```
def show
@genre = Genre.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Could you add a stack trace or log output from the 404 error? I'm trying to understand how the Genre.find that results in a 404 is occurring.

Comment: The thing which is confusing me now, is when i go on the 404 page and then run logs, it says that it cant find a movie with `id 13`. When i go to movies/13 it gives me another 404. I now for certain that movie with id 13 was never created. PLus it's weird that it gives me a 404 on the genre page because it cant find a movie, shouldnt it just give me a 500?

Comment: Post your controller action for Genres#show, perhaps?

Comment: Are you testing this in your local dev environment? If so, you should be getting a Rails debugging error page with 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound'. Is that the case? Such a page should include 'Couldn't find Genre with id=1034'. Is that so? Alternately, if you're getting 'Couldn't find Movie with id=13' you should be evaluating where, in your Genre#show view, you are trying to load up a particular Movie, and why it's not finding it.

Comment: I am testing in production mode, as that is where the error occurs.

Comment: Step 1: clone your database to your local dev setup. Step 2: test in development mode so you can get full, immediate feedback on problems. Step 3: write tests.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that Postgres is choosing its own id for that Genre and setting it. That's why you're getting a 404 error. The id you specify does not exist.

What do you get if you search for the Genre like so:

```
@genre = Genre.find_by_name("Comedy")
@genre.id
```

You are going to have consistent problems trying to override Postgres' id determination method. Are you unable to change the values in the Movies table? Why can't you just change the genre_id for the Movie record to match the Genre id that Postgres determines for that record?

**Alternate Fix**

I believe, if you really need to, that you can do this:

```
Genre.update_all("id = 1034", "name = 'Comedy'")
```

That [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) statement will change the id to 1034 for all records with name equal to Comedy, without running into the Rails/Postgres limits on setting ids manually.

Comment: If i run `@genre = Genre.find_by_name("Comedy")
@genre.id` the id is returned, so it gives me `1034`. The thing is is that the genre is being created when i create it and it is destroyed when i destroy it. My Problem is that it only gives me a 404 when i go to the specified id. 

if i do 
`Genre.update_all("id = 1034", "name = 'Comedy'")`, it will update the Genre id and change from the automatically set id to 1034 but it still gives me that 404

Comment: If, on Genres#index, you do for each genre `link_to genre.name, genre`, what does that link output for URL, and does it work when you click on it?

Comment: If i hover over the show action in the index page, I can see in the Status bar in safari that it does infact link to `http://localhost:3000/genres/1034`

When i click on it take me to `http://localhost:3000/genres/1034` but still gives me a 404

Comment: if i create a new genre (without specifying an id), and click show in the index, it'll take me to the page WITHOUT a 404

Comment: Can you post, in your question, the model code for Genre and a dump of the database table config for Genre as well?

Comment: I dont understand for the _dump of the database table config_ ??

Comment: Okay, don't worry about that: I was trying to figure out if there was something weird with model attributes or database columns causing the Genre not to be found via that id.